# When should titles like "captain" or "admiral" be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, honorifics

Please excuse the contrived example below, but I am wondering if this example is properly capitalised? I'm assuming that capitals are used when addressing someone directly, but lower case is used elsewhere.
Can someone give some rules on this?

> The captain walked into the room. 
>   "Hi, Captain," said the admiral.
>   "Hi, Sir," replied the captain.
>   "Call me Admiral."
>   "Hi Admiral."
>   The captain and admiral stepped forward.
>   "Prime Minister, this is Captain Jones," said Admiral Brown.
>   "Pleased to meet you," said the prime minister.

Comment: All correct, except that "sir" here is not a title and should not be capitalized. If you were talking about "Sir Winthrop of Cornwall" or some such that it would be a title, but here it's just a polite address. (Unless we're assuming that the admiral is a member of the nobility.)

Comment: I wondered about that one, which is why I included it in the example. I just thought of another one- what about colloquial words such as sis for sister - would that ever be capitalised in dialogue? I look at both versions and feel lower case could be confusing (as it's not a real word and so would rely on context) and to capitalise just looks wrong. I suspect after the comment above it wouldn't be capitalised (unless it came at the start of a sentence). I'm doing yet another final edit on a manuscript and like to get this stuff right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks right to me. The rules of capitalisation (based on the *Chicago Manual of Style*) are explained quite well on [this page](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/capital.asp). One of the rules relevant to this question is as follows:

**Rule 3**

> Capitalize a person's title when it precedes the name. Do not capitalize when the title is acting as a description following the name.

*Examples:*

> Chairperson Petrov
>
> Ms. Petrov, the chairperson of the company, will address us at noon.

Comment: Marking this as the answer for the link that has a good set of examples. I find this confusing for some reason, maybe it just doesn't look right in my eyes sometimes. Thanks for the other answers too.

Comment: Would be helpful if the answer actually quoted a single example. Otherwise it could be obsolete in no time. Link rot happens.

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA Point taken. I have added one of the rules applicable here.

Comment: @coleopterist: Given your example, would you consider it correct to say that a _title_ (Chairperson Petrov) needs to be capitalized, but a _role_ (chairperson of the company) does not?

Answer (score 5):

At least according to *CMOS*, there are a few rules that apply. (Your mileage may vary with AP or Oxford rules, I just happen to have *CMOS* within grabbing distance.)

7.16 says that titles used in place of names in direct address are capitalized. (e.g., "'Hi, Captain'")

7.17 says that titles used alone in place of a name are generally lowercased (e.g., "replied the captain").

(Edit: Cited the wrong rule.)

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. Titles are capitalized only when they appear with a name or when they are used to address. Otherwise, when the word stand alone, it is not capitalized.

Usually, when the titles is local only to a group or an  organization, it is NOT capitalized, eg:"the disaster management head, Mr. X"....

Answer (score 1):

Like Coleopterist said, the capitalization is good, the formality is a bit off though. If you were trying to have a conversation with a Captain or an Admiral it would be a bit more formal like, Good evening or Good Afternoon, unless they are good friends. I understand this is really off topic and that you said that you tried to make it look artificial but formality is also important.

Comment: You make a good point; the original question is concerned with etiquette, and your contribution is valid.  Please avoid using phrases like, "this will probably get a lot of downvotes."