# Do we capitalize job titles after a person's name?

Tags: punctuation, capitalization

Should professional, occupational and official titles be capped after a person's name?

*Mike McCormack, Human Resources Director for the XYZ corporation, resigned on Friday.*

If we use the definite article *the*, do we go lowercase?

*Mike McCormack, the human resources director for the XYZ corporation, resigned on Friday.*

*The human resources director, Mike McCormack, resigned on Friday.*

But:

*Human Resources Director Mike McCormack resigned on Friday.*

Are the four variations of the same sentence punctuated correctly?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/75252/8019

Answer (score 0):

Yes to all (unless "The" is part of the title).  A title is a proper name, so capitalize.  If you substitute a description ("the director of human resources" or "the human resources department head") then do not capitalize.

Comment: But in the example given 'Mike McCormack, the Human Remains Director, I would capitalise. However if I were simply to refer to the human-resources department in text, or to the need to appoint a human resources specialist, I probably wouldn't. It becomes a fine choice, but generally where a specific individual is referenced I would tend to capitalise.