# Capitalising the second word in a compound role-title

Tags: capitalization

When a title, made of two hyphenated words, is followed by a proper noun, is the word after the hyphen capitalised?

Eg. I understand that the following statement is correct:

> He killed King Ravan.

But, which of these is correct?

> He killed Demon-king Ravan.
>
> He killed Demon-King Ravan.

British English rules are what I, as an Indian, would prefer.

Thank you. :)

Comment: [This question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75252/capitalisation-of-titles) appears to answer a lot of this. Could you edit your question to say what is left that that doesn't cover? Otherwise, this is really a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Clarified the question in the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are his title and name King Ravan and is he a demon, then: "demon King Ravan." 
Is Ravan een demon-king, then "demon-king Ravan". 
Is demon-king a title, the "Demon-king Ravan."

Comment: Thank you. What's the “een” in your answer's second statement?